# Hide or display checkboxes if checked or not JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I got a problem with some checkboxes, I don't succeed to filter them according if they are checked or not.

The principle is simple. If I click on "All" all the checkboxes are displayed, but if I click on selected, I just want to see the checkboxes selected and hidde the ones unchecked.

Here is a snippet, please update it in your answer to let me see how it could be done.

Thanks a lot !

```js
//array of options
var choices = new Array();
choices[0] = "January";
choices[1] = "February";
choices[2] = "March";
choices[3] = "April";
choices[4] = "May";
choices[5] = "Juny";
choices[6] = "July";
choices[7] = "August";
choices[8] = "September";
choices[9] = "October";
choices[10] = "November";
choices[11] = "December";

var target = new Array()
target[0] = "5";
target[1] = "8";

var cbh = document.getElementById('checkboxes');
var val = '';
var cap = "";

var j = "";
var t = document.getElementById('t');

// the loop is creating the checkboxes with name, value...
for (var i in choices) {
  //Name of checkboxes are their number so I convert the i into a string. 
  j = i.toString();

  val = j;
  //cap will be the value/text of choices[i]
  var cb = document.createElement('input');
  var label = document.createElement("label");

  cap = choices[i];
  var text = document.createTextNode(cap);
  cb.type = 'checkbox';
  cbh.appendChild(cb);
  cb.name = cap;
  cb.value = val;
  label.appendChild(cb);
  label.appendChild(text);
  cbh.appendChild(label);
  cb.addEventListener('click', updateText)
  if(target.indexOf(i)>=0){
    cb.checked =true ;
  }

}
updateText();
function updateText() {
  t.value = [null, ...document.querySelectorAll('#checkboxes [type="checkbox"]')].reduce((s, el) => el && el.checked ? s = (s || '') + el.value + '$#' : s || '')
}
```

```css
   * {
       box-sizing: border-box;
   }
   #data {
       padding:5px;
    width:100vw;
   }
   .multiselect {
    overflow: visible;
    padding:0;
    padding-left:1px;
    border:none;
    background-color:#eee;
    width:100vw;
    white-space: normal;
    height:200px;
   }
   .checkboxes {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    background-color:white;
    margin-left:-1px;
    display:inline-block;
   }
      
            label {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px grey solid;
    padding:5px;
   }
```

```html
 <span onclick="">All</span> | <span onclick="">Selected</span>
 <form>
 <div id="data">
  <div class="multiselect">
   <div id="c_b">
    <div id="checkboxes">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
<textarea id="t"></textarea>
```

Comment: What have you tried for All/Selected?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with two functions, the first show all parents of inputs, the second hiden all parents of inputs that are not checked.

```
function All() {
  $("input").parent().show();
}

function OnlySelecteds() {
  $("input:not(:checked)").parent().hide();
}
```

```js
//array of options
var choices = new Array();
choices[0] = "January";
choices[1] = "February";
choices[2] = "March";
choices[3] = "April";
choices[4] = "May";
choices[5] = "Juny";
choices[6] = "July";
choices[7] = "August";
choices[8] = "September";
choices[9] = "October";
choices[10] = "November";
choices[11] = "December";

var target = new Array()
target[0] = "5";
target[1] = "8";

var cbh = document.getElementById('checkboxes');
var val = '';
var cap = "";

var j = "";
var t = document.getElementById('t');

// the loop is creating the checkboxes with name, value...
for (var i in choices) {
  //Name of checkboxes are their number so I convert the i into a string. 
  j = i.toString();

  val = j;
  //cap will be the value/text of choices[i]
  var cb = document.createElement('input');
  var label = document.createElement("label");

  cap = choices[i];
  var text = document.createTextNode(cap);
  cb.type = 'checkbox';
  cbh.appendChild(cb);
  cb.name = cap;
  cb.value = val;
  label.appendChild(cb);
  label.appendChild(text);
  cbh.appendChild(label);
  cb.addEventListener('click', updateText)
  if (target.indexOf(i) >= 0) {
    cb.checked = true;
  }

}
updateText();

function updateText() {
  t.value = [null, ...document.querySelectorAll('#checkboxes [type="checkbox"]')].reduce((s, el) => el && el.checked ? s = (s || '') + el.value + '$#' : s || '')
}

function All() {
  $("input").parent().show();
}

function OnlySelecteds() {
  $("input:not(:checked)").parent().hide();
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#data {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100vw;
}

.multiselect {
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 1px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 100vw;
  white-space: normal;
  height: 200px;
}

.checkboxes {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: -1px;
  display: inline-block;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px grey solid;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span onclick="All()" style="cursor:pointer">All</span> | <span onclick="OnlySelecteds()" style="cursor:pointer">Selected</span>
<form>
  <div id="data">
    <div class="multiselect">
      <div id="c_b">
        <div id="checkboxes">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<textarea id="t"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could select all the checked elements with `checked` selector, so you could show/hide its parent:

```
  $("#chkAll").click(function(){
    $(":checkbox").parent().show();
  });

  $("#chkSelected").click(function(){
    $(":checkbox").parent().hide();
    $(":checked").parent().show();
  });
```

Here your updated snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  //array of options
  var choices = new Array();
  choices[0] = "January";
  choices[1] = "February";
  choices[2] = "March";
  choices[3] = "April";
  choices[4] = "May";
  choices[5] = "Juny";
  choices[6] = "July";
  choices[7] = "August";
  choices[8] = "September";
  choices[9] = "October";
  choices[10] = "November";
  choices[11] = "December";

  var target = new Array()
  target[0] = "5";
  target[1] = "8";

  var cbh = document.getElementById('checkboxes');
  var val = '';
  var cap = "";

  var j = "";
  var t = document.getElementById('t');

  // the loop is creating the checkboxes with name, value...
  for (var i in choices) {
    //Name of checkboxes are their number so I convert the i into a string. 
    j = i.toString();

    val = j;
    //cap will be the value/text of choices[i]
    var cb = document.createElement('input');
    var label = document.createElement("label");

    cap = choices[i];
    var text = document.createTextNode(cap);
    cb.type = 'checkbox';
    cbh.appendChild(cb);
    cb.name = cap;
    cb.value = val;
    label.appendChild(cb);
    label.appendChild(text);
    cbh.appendChild(label);
    cb.addEventListener('click', updateText)
    if(target.indexOf(i)>=0){
      cb.checked =true ;
    }

  }
  updateText();
  function updateText() {
    t.value = [null, ...document.querySelectorAll('#checkboxes [type="checkbox"]')].reduce((s, el) => el && el.checked ? s = (s || '') + el.value + '$#' : s || '')
  }

  $("#chkAll").click(function(){
    $(":checkbox").parent().show();
  });

  $("#chkSelected").click(function(){
    $(":checkbox").parent().hide();
    $(":checked").parent().show();
  });
});
```

```css
* {
       box-sizing: border-box;
   }
   #data {
       padding:5px;
    width:100vw;
   }
   .multiselect {
    overflow: visible;
    padding:0;
    padding-left:1px;
    border:none;
    background-color:#eee;
    width:100vw;
    white-space: normal;
    height:200px;
   }
   .checkboxes {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    background-color:white;
    margin-left:-1px;
    display:inline-block;
   }
      
            label {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px grey solid;
    padding:5px;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="chkAll">All</span> | <span id="chkSelected">Selected</span>
 <form>
 <div id="data">
  <div class="multiselect">
   <div id="c_b">
    <div id="checkboxes">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
<textarea id="t"></textarea>
```